# XML File Using Azure Data Factory

Tags: xml, azure, azure-data-factory

I have used the latest xml file system support feature available in the Azure data factory to convert a  2 GB xml file to csv using copy activity, but it ended up in a memory exception. But if I use a lesser sized files , eg: 500 mb one, the file gets processed within 1 hour without any parallelism a or DIU. The 2 GB file doesnt get converted even if I use all the permutation combinations of parallelism, DIU, or Block size? Am I doing something wrong. If anyone could suggest a solution, it would be really helpful.

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try the XML to CSV conversion using Data Flow instead if you are experiencing issues with the standard Copy activity. I would also suggest you provision a memory optimized integration runtime to execute you data flow activity.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I am trying it with data flow now.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if you find it helpful.